# decimal place is lost when using number datatype

Tags: oracle11g

There is a field named MS_LTIME_STND in my table T and its datatype is number,  I update this field with 1.1 or -0.1 then I use:

```
select MS_LTIME_STND from T;
```

I got the result is 1 and 0, I don't know why the decimal place was lost, and how can I display this decimal place while using select statement without changing for this field's datatype?

I just want to show the value as I updated exactly.

Comment: What database is used?

Comment: Are you sure that the type of the column is just a NUMBER. Not NUMBER(n,0) for example?

Comment: Oracle 11g. I use desc T to check the datatype, it is NUMBER(38)

Comment: That's the problem: NUMBER(38) = NUMBER(38, 0) - you cannot store decimals there. Oracle rounds them to integers

Comment: Alter you table an make the column type NUMBER or NUMBER(38, s) where s is the scale, or the number of digits from the decimal point to the least significant digit.